# ReactiveUI Validation Does not raise Error Notification And Failed To BindValidation

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

**Hello,**
I try to use [ReactiveUI.Validation package](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation)
To Validate Wpf Simple App
And Validation works `i can see it in ViewModel valid state`
But I can not see any notification to view element
I mean no red border or any type of error appear, even when using MaterialDesignPackage, Custome Templates `nothing works!`

ViewModel.cs

```
public class AddNewUserViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject<AddNewUserViewModel>
{
    private string _email;
    public string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _email, value);
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit,Unit> Start { get; }
    public AddNewUserViewModel()
    {
        var vEmailHelper = this
            .ValidationRule(viewModel => viewModel.Email, e => e?.Length > 2, "Error Email Message");
        var canStart = this.IsValid();
        Start = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => { }, canStart);
    }
}
```

View.cs

```
public partial class AddNewUserDialogView : ReactiveWindow<AddNewUserViewModel>
{
    public AddNewUserDialogView()
    {
        ViewModel = new AddNewUserViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
        {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Email, v => v.EmailTextBox.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposable);
            this.BindCommand(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Start, v => v.ButStart).DisposeWith(disposable);
        });
    }
}
```

View.cs.xaml

```xml
<reactiveUi:ReactiveWindow x:TypeArguments="dialogs:AddNewUserViewModel"
                           x:Class="UsersManager.UI.Views.Body.Dialogs.AddNewUserDialogView"
                           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UsersManager.UI.Views.Body.Dialogs"
                           xmlns:reactiveUi="http://reactiveui.net"
                           xmlns:dialogs="clr-namespace:UsersManager.Backend.ViewModels.Body.Dialogs;assembly=UsersManager.Backend"
                           mc:Ignorable="d"

                           Title="test" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="EmailTextBox"
            materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Name"
            materialDesign:HintAssist.HelperText="Your user name"
        >
        </TextBox>

        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="ButStart"
            >Start</Button>
    </Grid>
</reactiveUi:ReactiveWindow>
```

If my EmailText does not match the rule, The button disabled, and this ok
But I can not see any behavior of validation in TextBox control itself?
`I try it with ErrorTemplate but not work also`

So how can I show an error or even get any error notifications in view

Also notice: `May open it as new question`

When I try to bind validation message of specific property it failed

```
public partial class AddNewUserDialogView : ReactiveWindow<AddNewUserViewModel>
{
    public AddNewUserDialogView()
    {
        ViewModel = new AddNewUserViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
        {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Email, v => v.EmailTextBox.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposable);
            this.BindCommand(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Start, v => v.ButStart).DisposeWith(disposable);

            // here
            this.BindValidation(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Email, v => v.ButStart.Content).DisposeWith(disposable);
        });
    }
}
```

With error :

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

This error occurs in `CurrentThreadScheduler.cs` of ReactiveUI
At Line `107`

This is a code snippet error location

```
// Line 85
 SchedulerQueue<TimeSpan> queue;

            // There is no timed task and no task is currently running
            if (!_running)
            {
                _running = true;

                if (dueTime > TimeSpan.Zero)
                {
                    ConcurrencyAbstractionLayer.Current.Sleep(dueTime);
                }

                // execute directly without queueing
                IDisposable d;
                try
                {
                    d = action(this, state);
                }
                catch
                {
                    SetQueue(null);
                    _running = false;
                    throw; // Line 107
                }
```

But

When I try to bind The Total/ Ultimate ViewModel error messages it works!

```
public partial class AddNewUserDialogView : ReactiveWindow<AddNewUserViewModel>
{
    public AddNewUserDialogView()
    {
        ViewModel = new AddNewUserViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
        {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Email, v => v.EmailTextBox.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposable);
            this.BindCommand(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Start, v => v.ButStart).DisposeWith(disposable);

            // here
            this.BindValidation(ViewModel, v => v.ButStart.Content).DisposeWith(disposable);
        });
    }
}
```

resources : i think may be useful

```
 https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation/issues/16
 https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation/pull/17
 https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation/pull/44
```

Packages

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ActiproSoftware.BarCode.Wpf, Version=17.2.663.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=36ff2196ab5654b9, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="ActiproSoftware.Shared.Wpf, Version=17.2.663.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=36ff2196ab5654b9, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="DynamicData, Version=6.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\DynamicData.6.14.8\lib\net461\DynamicData.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit, Version=5.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cc39be672370310, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AvalonEdit.5.0.4\lib\Net40\ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MaterialDesignColors, Version=1.2.2.920, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MaterialDesignColors.1.2.2\lib\net45\MaterialDesignColors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, Version=3.0.1.920, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MaterialDesignThemes.3.0.1\lib\net45\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="Pharmacist.Common, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Pharmacist.Common.1.5.15\lib\netstandard2.0\Pharmacist.Common.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework.Aero" />
    <Reference Include="ReactiveUI, Version=11.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ReactiveUI.11.2.3\lib\net461\ReactiveUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ReactiveUI.Events.WPF, Version=11.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ReactiveUI.Events.WPF.11.2.3\lib\net461\ReactiveUI.Events.WPF.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers, Version=11.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ReactiveUI.Fody.11.2.3\lib\net461\ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ReactiveUI.Validation, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ReactiveUI.Validation.1.4.10\lib\net461\ReactiveUI.Validation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ReactiveUI.WPF, Version=11.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ReactiveUI.WPF.11.2.3\lib\net461\ReactiveUI.WPF.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ShowMeTheXAML, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ShowMeTheXAML.1.0.12\lib\net45\ShowMeTheXAML.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ShowMeTheXAML.AvalonEdit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ShowMeTheXAML.AvalonEdit.1.0.12\lib\net45\ShowMeTheXAML.AvalonEdit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Splat, Version=9.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Splat.9.3.11\lib\net461\Splat.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Reactive, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Reactive.4.3.2\lib\net46\System.Reactive.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.2\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

### Updates

I Solve the second problem With very strange modification

### This must not be considered a real solution

I just listen to validation status changes

In View

```
ViewModel.ValidationContext.ValidationStatusChange.Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    // if i omite next line , the solution will not work
                    MessageBox.Show("Start");
                });
```

And Now Validation Message Appear

```
 // so: now this line will not produce argument out of range exception
 this.BindValidation(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Email, v => v.ButStart.Content).DisposeWith(disposable);
```

Also notice: if I listen directly from viewModel the solution will also work

`I tested it in another project`

But here I separate it because I use different projects from UI/Backend`contains ViewModels`

Also notice this will work if I listen to any other validator

So if I expose email ValidationHelper as property out of ViewModel and subscribe to it, this will work,

Also if I just subscribe/listen to email ValidationHelper from ViewModel this will work also

But remember, I still need to call MessageBox.Show("")

Notice: This will work if I Call ShowDialog() on any Window even MainWindow

So the next Solution will also work

```
ViewModel.ValidationContext.ValidationStatusChange.Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    var v = new MainWindow();
                    v.ShowDialog();
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding the validation to a control template is currently not supported but you can show a validation error message in the view if you bind it to a seperate textblock ([Documentation](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/user-input-validation/)).

If you just want to use the MaterialDesign HelperText to show an error message, you don't need to use ReactiveUI.Validation but could do something like this:

```
    // Viewmodel
    private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> isEmailValid;
    public bool IsEmailValid => isEmailValid.Value;
    ...
    isEmailValid = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Email).Select(e => e?.Length > 2).ToProperty(this, nameof(IsEmailValid));

    // View
    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.IsEmailValid)
        .Do(isValid => HintAssist.SetHint(EmailTextBox, isValid ? string.Empty : "Error Email Message"))
        .Subscribe();
```

Your second problem should be fixed when you use the latest version of ReactiveUI.Validation [(1.4.13)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReactiveUI.Validation/).

Comment: Thank You, I Solve the first problem by creating another library to solve the first problem for ReactiveUI [Validation] and it works very well, but it is required two steps, one in view and other in viewModel and in ViewModel it is required to inherit from another class so may reactive UI team refuse to add it, so will try to improve it and publish it. I will mention that here in question [edit]